# Wrong polygons displayed in QGIS spatial query

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, query

I have two polygons, one is a virtual layer that generates a buffer around a site, the other is a set of polygons representing locations of interest.

[image]

I have tried to create a query that gives me only the locations of interest that intersect with my buffer:

[image]

This works, but when I add this as a new layer, it results in a polygon the size of the buffer, instead of giving me a selection of sites of interest that intersect with the buffer:

[image]

I would like the resulting layer to represent the locations of interest that intersect instead of the buffer itself, how do I manage this?

I try to use a virtual layer so that when I redraw my buffer, the same selection of information is generated elsewhere without extra actions

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 geometry column in your query, and the 1st one is used by default. You can remove it (`"buffer 100m".geometry`) or put it in 2nd, or declare the geometry column in the options below the query